# Unable to download crash information

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to download crash information in order to fix a particularly trying and tiresome bug.  Unfortunately, whenever I do so (Xcode, Window -> Organizer, click on iOS App Name, click on Crashes tab) I get the error:

Unable to download crash information
None of your developer accounts are authorised to access crash information for LocoApp. Verify that your developer accounts are correctly configured in Xcode, then try again.

What additional permissions do I need?  I can't find this error anywhere on the internet - surely I can't be the first to see it?

Comment: Well I searched the internet and couldn't find any reference to it.  If you could supply a link, I will happily don a paper bag in honour of my stupidity at not finding the relevant information…

Comment: No - I'm afraid not.  It's very frustrating - and, when I find the answer, I'll be sure to post it here.  If you manage to find it first, please post the solution up!

Comment: @headbanger still no solution? Im having the same problem

Comment: @headbanger same problem here, any solution?

Comment: In my case I'll get this error on some days, and on other days the crash logs will appear as expected. Is that what other people are seeing?

Comment: Are you able to "Upload to App Store" using the Organizer? Also, which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I can upload to the app store using the organiser, and I'm using (currently) Xcode 7.1 (7B91b).  It happened with previous versions too.

Comment: [This is the only link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12244) I can find that relates. I don't suppose your specs match the OP's in that thread?

Comment: @headbanger Did the answer fix it? Or are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 5):

**All credits to this answer go to "Adrian Sluyters".**

---

After a bit of research I found [this](http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/e2c673834505/xcode-unable-to-download-crash-information.html) link. It's the same question and someone actually answered it (and it was marked as viable solution), so here you go:

---

- 1) Visit the apple dev page (https://developer.apple.com).
- 2) Log in with your Agent/Admin ID.
- 3) Click on "iOS" below "Technical Resources and Tools" -> "Dev Centers"
- 4) Choose "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" from the list on the right side.
- 5) On the following page you have to choose "Devices", located below "iOS Apps".

Register the device that you want to get the logs from. You need a nickname for the device (whatever you like) and the UDID. You can get the UDID by plugging in your device and running iTunes. After the popup with the recognized device appears you'll just have to click "Serial number" and you'll get various informations including the UDID.

When you're done with that you'll need a developers certificate on your phone.

- 1) Step back to Step 4 mentioned above and choose "Certificates" -> "All"
- 2) You should see a certificate on the right side (if you do not, you'll have to create one by clicking the "+" and simply follow the on-screen instructions. Note: You'll want to create a **developers**, not **production** certificate!
- 3) After completing step 2 you'll be asked to download the certificate which you need to do.
- 4) Send the certificate to your device (i.e. email) and install it.

**Check out the link above, there were multiple answers regarding your problem. If this solution doesn't do it for you, one of the others might.**

Kind regards,

Seth

Answer (score 0):

In order to view crash logs gathered by Apple in Xcode, your developer account has to be linked to iTunes Connect.

If you are a single developer working on your own app, then most probably your developer account and iTunes Connect account are the same. However, if you work in a bigger organization, then your developer account may not have access to iTunes Connect. In that case, Xcode will not show you the crashlogs.

Log in iTunes Connect with Admin account, go to Users and Roles, enter names and the email of your developer account, click Next, then choose Developer role and proceed.

You will receive an email to activate your iTunes account. After that, restart your Xcode and the crashlogs will start coming into Organizer -> Crashes tab.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and this is how I (or actually Apple) was able to fix it.

I contacted iTunes Connect support via http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus/ (I guess you can send an email to devitc@apple.com directly as well, but I'm not sure you'll get a correct ticket/case number then.)

They requested screenshots, screen capture and some logs. After 1,5 week of sending emails back and forth, the Apple engineers were able to miraculously fix it. Unfortunately, my contact person was not told what the solution was (or he didn't want to tell me). My contact person's name is Bri, so maybe referring to that name will help.

Good luck, I hope this helps for you as well!

Comment: While I can appreciate that this process helped you, it's hard to imagine this being useful for anyone else in the future. I mean, knowing that you spoke with "Bri" is useful only while Bri remains employed in this capacity. Fundamentally, this answer boils down to "contact Apple for help."

Comment: It's the best I can get and it's by far the closest thing to an answer to this question to be found anywhere. I read that some other guy contacted Apple about this before and didn't get a real answer. So I think it's very useful to know that although the problem exists in Xcode, it can be fixed by contacting iTunes Connect support. Of course, I can provide a case number if that helps. Just wanted to help.